# How to use jsdoc in my script running on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, jsdoc

I would like to use `jsdoc` module to extract documentation entries from some source code.
I have installed `jsdoc` module and I can use `jsdoc` in the command line.
But when I `require("jsdoc")` in my code, nodejs throws an error saying `Cannot find module 'jsdoc'`.

I have nodejs v0.8.25 and JSDoc 3.3.0-alpha2. It is installed both locally and globally.
I can use `jsdoc` command and I have `jsdoc` in my `node_modules` folder.
I cannot see where the problem is.

Where can I find some documentation about `jsdoc` other than how to use it in the command line interface or how to document js source code. I would like some API documentation.

Comment: how did you install jsdoc? `npm install jsdoc --save`? Also, as a complete sidenote, you probably want to update your node to the latest 0.10.2x

Comment: I change to a latest version of nodejs and I install jsdoc with exactly this command. I can use it in command line interface. I still cannot require this module in my script.

Comment: can you update your post to indicate whether, after `npm install jsdoc --save` there is a `jsdoc` dir in your `node_modules` directory?

Answer (score 6):

I was looking to use jsdoc as a library too, and I stumbled on the same issue as you did.
You have done nothing wrong, it was just never intended to be used as a library.

There is [***an issue***](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/pull/548) on the jsdoc's github project page relating to this. [Hegemonic](https://github.com/hegemonic), the main contributor of JSDoc said:

> JSDoc isn't really designed to be used as a library

You might want to express your desire to for creating an API for nodejs on the issue linked above.

The `require('jsdoc')` fails because there is no `main` field declared in the jsdoc's `package.json`. It might default to 'index.js' or 'main.js', but there is no such file either.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you haven't installed jsdoc correctly. Run `npm install -g jsdoc` from your command line. If you run this inside a new terminal window that's in the default directory you shouldn't have any problems. I've had issues where I've tried to install a node module globally from my current working directory and for whatever reason the module doesn't install globally.

Answer (score -3):

If it is about an automatic documentation tool in general, you could also use [YUIDoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/).

Following these three steps, you will have your automatic documentation:

1. Installing it:  `npm -g install yuidocjs`
2. Format your comments regarding the [YUIDoc Syntax Reference](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/syntax/index.html)
3. In your console run `yuidoc .` on top of your JS source tree

Comment: The question is specifically about JSDoc.. while similar, JSDoc and YUIDoc use/require different doclets (and JSDoc supports "code inspection").